# Install a package manager without package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, debian, aptitude

I'm doing some work on a really, really minimalistic Debian dist and noticed that there is no package manager on it.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this? There is no GUI but I have an Internet connection.

Comment: Does that mean there's no apt or aptitude installed?

Comment: Are you actually talking about Ubuntu at all?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want to use it in a graphic environment, but you could try this:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude  synaptic
```

Aptitude works in a terminal, either trough commands or with an ncurses environment. Synaptic is my favourite GUI for installing and updating packages.

If what you mean is that you even lack off apt-get, which is weird... You'll need to download the corresponding .deb packages from the web for your architecture and install em with dpkg or gdebi. The syntax is always:

```
sudo dpkg -i <packagename.deb>

sudo gdebi <packagename.deb>
```

The difference is that gdebi looks for the dependencies and download them from the networdk, while dpkg would just complain and stop if there's any missing dependency.

Good luck!

Comment: Amazing how people fail to read the question properly. There is NO package manager installed on the system, then how would one use a package manager to install a package manager? It's the chicken egg problem you created.

Comment: dpkg is NOT a package manager, but a package installer. It doesn't resolve dependencies nor download them, just installs a package from a local file.